# Date time issue in spring boot application for different timezones

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am facing a date time issue in my spring boot application.My application is displaying different date and time for different time zones. I want that it should display the same date and time for all the time zones.

My web application is displaying time according to the timezone of my web browser. Is there any way possible so that my web application always display time in a specific time zone irrespective of the timezone of my web browser.

Comment: please add the codes what you wrote. It would be useful to answer

Comment: @ChathuraHennayaka I am facing this issue in my whole application is there any centralized way so that the date and time displayed by my application does not change according to the time zone of my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can set UTC time zone in your application based on UTC date and time you can get proper date and time 
Add the following  code in your Spring boot application

```
@PostConstruct
void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your `application.properties` this will solve your problem.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```